# Azure SQL DataBase Premium Edition not available

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created a new SQL Database Server in Azure SQL.
Why is it not possible to create a new Premium Edition database?
The button is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, new services or features are only available after you enable them from the preview page:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/preview/